# Cannot access a mounted drive in WSL

Tags: linux, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I cannot access my `E:/` drive suddenly on WSL, do not know why. When I try to change the directory to the E by `cd /mnt/e`, it does not suggest any further subfolders in that drive. Also the `ls` command shows-

`ls: cannot open directory '.': Invalid argument`

I tried unmounting and mounting it again but it did not work. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot?

Comment: How this works is different between WSL1 and WSL2 (I think)..  Somehow, those mount points get connected at boot.  I myself have needed to reboot to get drives back that weren't there on boot.  Kinda like @harrymc is eluding to.

Comment: Thanks, the reboot was needed. It is working fine now.

Comment: Sorry, but how is "reboot" a solution? I know rebooting will "fix" a ton of Windows issues,  at least temporarily, but rebooting is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

In WSL, Use

```bash
sudo mount -t drvfs DRIVE: /mnt/DRIVE
```

E.g.

```bash
sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d
```